# What is the take away from such ACF and PACF plot?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, acf-pacf

I plotted the ACF and PACF after taking the first difference of my time-series. What is the take away from such plots? What should be the AR and MA order in such case?

[image: Autocorrelation Plot]

[image: Partial Autocorrelation Plot]

The data is as follows,

```
EoQ         GDP    GDP-Diff
2017-09-01  810.7   NaN
2017-12-01  843.7   33.0
2017-03-01  863.4   19.7
2017-06-01  897.4   34.0
2018-09-01  853.0   -44.4
2018-12-01  888.5   35.5
2018-03-01  910.3   21.8
2018-06-01  945.1   34.8
2019-09-01  895.9   -49.2
2019-12-01  933.2   37.3
2019-03-01  958.6   25.4
```

[image: GDP Without Differencing]

[image: GDP With Differencing]

Comment: is this daily data ?

Comment: @IrishStat Quarterly (q1, q2, q3, q4)

Comment: the acf/pacf is a CLEAR indicator of the arma model if and only if 1)there are no pulses ; 2) there are no seasonal pulses ; 3) there are no level/step shifts ; 4) there no deterministic time trends ; 5) parameters of the arma model are invariant over time ; 6) model error variance is invariant over time. If any of these conditions are (seriously) violated then the acf/pacf may be of limited value. The acf at lag 5 for quarterly data may suggest the need for both a quarterly ar and a regular ar  ONLY YOUR DATA KNOWS FOR SURE. please post your original data .

Comment: @IrishStat I posted my data in a comment. Thank you.

Comment: If you like my answer please accept it to close the question

Answer (score 0):

Your 11 quarterly observations follow a (0,0,0)(0,1,0)4 model presented here [image] and here [image] with statistics here [image] and Actual, Fit and Forecasts here [image] . I used AUTOBOX which I have helped to develop to obtain these results.